# 'Positional argument follows keyword argument' error in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program for a project that plays like the game Exploding Atoms. However, I'm having problems getting the buttons at the start to work - the first button to quit does what it is meant to, but I'm trying to call a subroutine in with the second button and it can't, as the error 'positional argument follows keyword argument' comes up when I put the subroutine in as the command. I'm not sure if I'm writing it wrong? This is the code:

```
button_1 = tkinter.Button(frame,text = 'QUIT', width = '6', height = '2',command=quit)
button_1.pack(side=LEFT)

button_2 = tkinter.Button(frame,text = 'START', width = '6', height = '2',gridimp(gridcreate,_switch,draw,CellGrid,draw,_eventCoords,handleMouseClick,handleMouseMotion))
button_2.pack(side=LEFT)

exat_window = tkinter.Tk()
exat_window.title('Exploding Atoms')
frame = Frame(exat_window )
frame.pack()

exat_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: The `gridimp(...)` part is a positional argument, it can't be put after the `text`, `width` and `height` arguments. What were you hoping that that part would do?

Comment: If that's supposed to be the command, then make it a keyword argument: `command=gridimp`. You also should not call it right there, you want it to be called only when the button is clicked; perhaps you want to use a lambda instead? `command=lambda: gridimp(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a method in python you need to follow the method signature where it is defined.

First goes the positional arguments, then the keyword mapped arguments. I feel issue is with your this line:

```
button_2 = tkinter.Button(frame,text = 'START', width = '6', height = '2', gridimp(gridcreate,_switch,draw,CellGrid,draw,_eventCoords,handleMouseClick,handleMouseMotion))
```

Shall it be any of this two based what is your `gridimp()` is doing.

```
button_2 = tkinter.Button(frame, gridimp(gridcreate,_switch,draw,CellGrid,draw,_eventCoords,handleMouseClick,handleMouseMotion),text = 'START', width = '6', height = '2')
```

OR

```
button_2 = tkinter.Button(frame,text = 'START', width = '6', height = '2', command=gridimp(gridcreate,_switch,draw,CellGrid,draw,_eventCoords,handleMouseClick,handleMouseMotion))
```